# How to include an aggregate function inside a dplyr filter in R

Tags: r

I need to find out total number of models that were sold only once in a given month.

Sample DF:

```
> df <- data.frame(sale_date = c('2019-01-02','2019-01-06','2019-01-20','2019-01-24','2019-02- 
01','2019-02-11','2019-02-21','2019-03-13','2019-03-10','2019-03-19'),
+                  model = c('A4','Vxi','Vxi','A6','Xing','Xing','Lxi','Lxi','Zxi','Zxi'))
> df
    sale_date model
1  2019-01-02    A4
2  2019-01-06   Vxi
3  2019-01-20   Vxi
4  2019-01-24    A6
5  2019-02-01  Xing
6  2019-02-11  Xing
7  2019-02-21   Lxi
8  2019-03-13   Lxi
9  2019-03-10   Zxi
10 2019-03-19   Zxi
```

My output should be : 4, because in Jan both 'A4' and 'A6' where sold only once, so that's 2 for Jan, then in Feb 'Lxi' was sold only once, so 3 for Jan and Feb and in March also 'Lxi' was sold just once, so total models that were sold only once each month is 4.

tried with below code but seems lengthy:

```
> step1 <- df %>% group_by(month(sale_date, label = 1),model) %>% summarise(count = n())
> step1
# A tibble: 7 x 3
# Groups:   month(sale_date, label = 1) [3]
  `month(sale_date, label = 1)` model count
  <ord>                         <fct> <int>
1 Jan                           A4        1
2 Jan                           A6        1
3 Jan                           Vxi       2
4 Feb                           Lxi       1
5 Feb                           Xing      2
6 Mar                           Lxi       1
7 Mar                           Zxi       2
> sum(step1$count == 1)
[1] 4
>
```

Could someone let me know if there is a simpler code to get the result

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can get the month-year from the date, create a count of number of models sold in each month and count number of models that were sold only once.

```
library(dplyr)

df %>%
  mutate(sale_month = format(as.Date(sale_date), "%Y-%m")) %>%
  count(sale_month, model) %>%
  summarise(ans = sum(n == 1))

#    ans
#  <int>
#1     4
```

---

In base R, we can count the number of models sold with `table` and count the occurence of 1.

```
sum(table(transform(df,sale_month = format(as.Date(sale_date), "%Y-%m"))[-1]) ==1)
#[1] 4
```